# HTML, RTF, plain text reformatting in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, html

In Outlook 2010, when you Reply, Reply All or Forward, how can you force the email be HTML-formatted instead of inheriting the format of the original email?

Of particular interest, I have a problem where someone sends me messages formatted as RTF in Outlook, which creates problems where the non-plain text content may not be visible to people to whom I relay the messages.  I would like to be able to translate the messages to HTML when I resend them.

Answer (score 1):

Try the methods suggested by [MSOutlook.info](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/628)

**Method 1**: Change the message format manually

Click on `Reply` / `Reply All` / `Forward`
This will open up a new window, i.e., the e-mail editor
Go to the e-mail Toolbar / Ribbon  > click on tab `Format Text` > group `Format` > Select your preferred format

- **HTML** (use keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>)
- **Plain Text** (use keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>)
- **Rich Text** (RFT) (use keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>)

[image: screenshot]

**Note**: Only content in the body of the email will be reformatted as per your preference. There might be some inconsistencies, like too many indents, but otherwise its usually pain free. If the original message was formatted RTF in Outlook, all non-plain-text content, plus attachments, will have been stored in a `winmail.dat` attachment. Content within `winmail.dat` has to be viewed / recovered manually (requires a separate app).

---

**Method 2**: Macro
You can change the message format via a VBA macro [Source](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/always-reply-using-the-same-message-format/)

In Outlook, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor and expand `Microsoft Outlook Objects` then double click on `ThisOutlookSession` to open it in the editing pane and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to paste the code.

```vb
Option Explicit 

Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer 
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem 

Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean 
Private olFormat As OlBodyFormat 

Private Sub Application_Startup() 
    
   Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer 
    
   bDiscardEvents = False 
    
   'olFormat = olFormatPlain        '(*1) - reply using plain text  
   olFormat = olFormatHTML        '(*2) - reply using HTML 
    
End Sub 

Private Sub oExpl_SelectionChange() 

   On Error Resume Next 
   Set oItem = oExpl.Selection.Item(1) 
    
End Sub 

Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 

   If bDiscardEvents Or oItem.BodyFormat = olFormat Then 
       Exit Sub 
   End If 
    
   Cancel = True 

   bDiscardEvents = True 
    
   Dim oResponse As MailItem 
   Set oResponse = oItem.Reply 
   oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormat 
   oResponse.Display 
    
   bDiscardEvents = False 
    
End Sub 

Private Sub oItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 

   If bDiscardEvents Or oItem.BodyFormat = olFormat Then 
       Exit Sub 
   End If 

   Cancel = True 
  
   bDiscardEvents = True 
    
   Dim oResponse As MailItem 
   Set oResponse = oItem.ReplyAll 
   oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormat 
   oResponse.Display 
    
   bDiscardEvents = False 
    
End Sub 

Private Sub oItem_Forward(ByVal Forward As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
    
   If bDiscardEvents Or oItem.BodyFormat = olFormat Then 
       Exit Sub 
   End If 
    
   Cancel = True 

   bDiscardEvents = True 
    
   Dim oResponse As MailItem 
   Set oResponse = oItem.Forward 
   oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormat 
   oResponse.Display 
    
   bDiscardEvents = False 
    
End Sub
```

If you want your email to always be in plain text, then comment out the HTML line and uncomment the plain text line in the above code, like this:

```vb
olFormat = olFormatPlain '(*1) - always use plain text
'olFormat = olFormatHTML '(*2) - always use HTML
```

**Warning**: I haven't tested the code and using macros carries some risk if you don't know what you are doing. Use with care.

**Note**: This does not modify the original email in inbox

---

**Method 3**: Paid Add-in

There may be a way to automate this via a paid add-in: [Bells & Whistles for Outlook](https://www.emailaddressmanager.com/outlook-bells.html) ($29.95)

**Warning**: I have not tried this add-in and I don't recommend this unless you need the add-in for other reasons as well, and its worth paying for the extra features it offers.

Comment: Can you clarify whether everything is reformatted to the selected format vs. only new content.  For example, if you receive an RTF message where everything (images, attachments, etc.), is in a winmail.dat file and then set the output format to HTML, will all of the previous content be reformatted and integrated as if everything had originally been HTML, and the winmail.dat disappears?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the easiest method is a **free** add-in: [ReliefJet Quicks for Outlook](https://www.reliefjet.com/Quicks/Features/QuickTweaks). It provides the "Always reply using format" option that does exactly what you want (including formatting when forwarding and even more productivity tweaks). Just set the required format and forget.

It sets the format for your outgoing message, including everything in the entire message body, but note that it doesn't re-integrate what the originator's Outlook may have moved to the winmail.dat file (such as original enhanced message formatting, embedded images, hyperlinks in usable form, or attachments).

Please note that I recommend this add-in because I'm one of its developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: It forces the format for the entire reply message.

Comment: Outlook stores additional MAPI properties in TNEF format (that is winmail.dat file). It is not related to message body and you can disable TNEF usage in Outlook/Exchange options.

Comment: The OP's question was one of a pair.  The related question explained the problem in more detail.  The issue was somebody creating their messages in RTF in Outlook.  Outlook dumps everything into the winmail.dat file and leaves a plain text copy of the message body.  So among the things in winmail.dat are the original message formatting, hyperlinks in usable form, images that may have been embedded in the message, attachments, etc.  So I was trying to clarify whether your add-in deals with just the current message body, or re-integrates original body content from winmail.dat.  Thanks.

Comment: No, it will not re-integrate anything, because Outlook processes winmail.dat in the incoming messages automatically. You just don't even see it. For outgoing messages add-in can force HTML format for RTF body and the recipients will not receive the winmail.dat.